# Why would someone select/change a specific logging framework at deployment time?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I am reading about logging using java and came across this: [enter link description here](http://www.slf4j.org/index.html)
It talks about an advantage of slf4j here that:
One can select his logging framework at deployment time ==> The desired logging framework can be plugged in at deployment time by inserting the appropriate jar file (binding) on your class path.
Can someone explain to me why and where we would need this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're writing a generic-pupose library, which generates logs using SLF4J.

Company A uses it, and has already configured all its IT infrastructure to use log4J. They're happy that your API can also use log4J to log.

Company B uses it as well, and has already configured all its IT infrastructure to use java util logging. They're happy that your API can also use java util logging to log.

Company C uses it as well, and has already configured all its IT infrastructure to use logback. They're happy that your API can also use logback to log.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of the following scenario:

- Websphere uses JCL logging, if also using JCL, then you can set/modify log levels and filters at runtime.
- Appserver X is more geared towards Log4J, so might be better to use that...

With SLF4J you don't need to refactor the code for the underlying logging framework to use...